# Handle multiple environments for authorizationUrl and tokenUrl in Open API spec

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is it possible to somehow template the base path for `authorizationUrl` and `tokenUrl` in an oauth2 security scheme to handle multiple environments (e.g. dev, sit, uat)?

The company where I work has a separate IDP tenant per environment and services in each environment will validate tokens against a specific tenant/issuer.

Ideally I could define and select the tenant base URL similar to how I can template servers for API routes - see [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/).
[image]

My `securitySchemes` currently looks like this:

```
"securitySchemes": {
    "oauth": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "flows": {
            "authorizationCode": {
                "authorizationUrl": "https://tenant-dev.au.auth0.com/authorize?audience=test",
                "tokenUrl": "https://tenant-dev.au.auth0.com/oauth/token"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only multi-environment approach that I can think of so far is to use the following security scheme config which allows me to specify any JWT. The drawback is that I still need to obtain the JWT by some external means...

```
"securitySchemes": {
    "oauth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer",
        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
    }
}
```

Notes;

- we're using external IDP so the IDP base URL does not overlap with the service base URLs.
- Swagger UI won't be accessible in production environment, but there's still dev, sit and uat.

Comment: OpenAPI doesn't support templated OAuth endpoints, here's the existing enhancement request: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/551

Comment: Thanks Helen. Good to see other people have thought about / requested a similar feature :)