# make AuthorizationUrl configurable in swagger ui using Swashbuckle 6.0.5 in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is it possible to have a input for AuthorizationUrl when using OAuth2 with Implicit flow as SecurityDefinition in swagger in asp.net core ?

My goal is to make AuthorizationUrl dynamic, so when the user sees the modal for entering clientId for the OAuth2 he can also change AuthorizationUrl .

Comment: Possibly related: [Handle multiple environments for `authorizationUrl` and `tokenUrl` in an OpenAPI spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64112451/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither OpenAPI Specification nor Swagger UI support this. The `authorizationUrl` is hard-coded and [cannot be parameterized](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/551). Different OAuth identity providers need to be defined as separate security schemes.

However, `authorizationUrl`  can be defined [relative to the API server URL](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/#relative-url), which itself [can be relative](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/#relative-urls) to the location of the OpenAPI YAML/JSON file.